# Есть ли встроенные процедуры сортировок в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Нужно сделать прогу, которая бы сортировала список по определённому полю. Но писать самому сортировку лень. Есть ли встроенные процедуры в Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Delphi есть `TList` который может хранить произвольные типы данных и позволяет их сортировать. Метод `TList.Sort()`, в качестве аргумента принимает вашу функцию сортировки. Сортировка списка проводится внутри `TList` (используется `QuickSort`), но каждая пара элементов сравнивается, вызывая функцию, которую вы указали для этого метода.

Минимальный пример, который показывает как можно отсортировать список по тому или иному полю, просто подставив нужную функцию сортировки:

```
uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

type
  TListItem = record
    F1: string;
    F2: Integer;
  end;
  PListItem = ^TListItem;

function CompareByF1(Item1, Item2: Pointer): Integer;
begin
   Result := CompareText(PListItem(Item1).F1, PListItem(Item2).F1);
end;

function CompareByF2(Item1, Item2: Pointer): Integer;
begin
   Result := PListItem(Item1).F2 - PListItem(Item2).F2;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  I: Integer;
  VList: TList;
  VTestItem: PListItem;
begin
  VList := TList.Create;
  try
    try
      // заполнение списка данными
      for I := 9 downto 0 do begin
        New(VTestItem); // динамическое выделение памяти для элемента списка
        VTestItem.F1 := 'TestStr#' + IntToStr(I);
        VTestItem.F2 := I;
        VList.Add(VTestItem);
      end;

      // тестовая перчать списка ДО сортировки
      for I := 0 to VList.Count - 1 do begin
        Writeln(PListItem(VList.Items[I]).F1);
      end;
      Writeln;

      VList.Sort(CompareByF2); // сортировка по нужному нам полю

      // тестовая перчать списка ПОСЛЕ сортировки
      for I := 0 to VList.Count - 1 do begin
        Writeln(PListItem(VList.Items[I]).F1);
      end;
    finally
      for I := 0 to VList.Count - 1 do begin
        Dispose(VList.Items[I]); // освобождение ранее выделенной памяти
      end;
    end;
  finally
    VList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

А вот тут: [How do I sort a generic list using a custom comparer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252367/6219657) есть пример, как сортировать список, в версиях Delphi с поддержкой дженериков.